# Java Cassandra driver migration from 3 to 4

Tags: java, cassandra, driver

I'm currently migrating java Cassandra driver from version 3.x to 4.x and have difficulties to set our wanted config on the new driver.

I understand that the `Cluster` class is gone and replaced with `CqlSession`, just have no idea how to migrate these:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    ...
    // how can i migrate these to be used in CqlSession ???
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)
    .withCompression(ProtocolOptions.Compression.LZ4)
    .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(LOCAL_QUORUM))
    .build();
```

Any idea how to move this to the new driver? Can these be somehow set on `CqlSessionBuilder` or do I have to use something totally different?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration has been completely refactored in Java driver 4. The recommendation is to use the [reference configuration file](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/configuration/reference/) for the configurable options. For example, you would define compression options with:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  advanced.protocol.compression = lz4 // or snappy
}
```

or set the consistency level based on an execution profile:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  profiles {
    oltp {
      basic.request.timeout = 1000 milliseconds
      basic.request.consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
  }
}
```

For details, have a look at the [Java driver 4.x Upgrade Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/upgrade_guide/) as a starting point. Then check out the following pages for reference:

- [Configuration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/configuration/)
- [Load balancing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/load_balancing/)
- [Compression](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/compression/)

If you're interested, check out the [**Java driver sample app at Astra**](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) that provides you all the code you need to get started really quickly. Cheers!

Comment: thank you very much. I would maybe have one more question. We currently use a custom stateful LoadBalancingPolicy. Is there some way to insert a LoadBalancing object that already has some dependencies in it instead of just passing int a LoadBalancing class?

Comment: I'm not sure. Let me reach out to the Driver devs at DataStax and will come back with an update. Cheers!